# iOS setting app badge value

Tags: ios, background-process, badge

It is clear *how* to set the badge number:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = whatever
```

The problem is *when* to increment it properly. I want it to equal the number of UILocalNotifications that have fired since the app went to sleep. The notifications themselves have a badge value, but that requires you to know *in advance* the value. Also, a notification can be recurring, so its count/badge value is not clearly defined. (At creation time. Do I have to keep resetting the badge numbers of notifications every time the app wakes?)

If the OS would notify the app (in the background) as well as the user, the app could easily update a static count and set the badge number.

It seems that in iOS 8 there is a registerUserNotificationSettings call, which *might* enable the OS to do the counting automatically. I don't know. But in any case, how is this done in previous OSes?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't, the badge number on the icon is not cumulative and will always reflect the one set in the local or remote notification.